# Triggering a Click event in jquery upon navigating to the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following navigation:

```
<ul id="chooseType" class="chooseType">
<li><a id="active" href="#" title="" class="active selected">Active</a></li>
<li><a id="inactive" href="#" title="" class="inactive">Inactive</a></li>
</ul>
```

With this script:

```
        <script th:inline="javascript">
                            /*<![CDATA[*/
                            $(document).ready(function() {

                                $('#active').click(function(){
                                    $('#active').addClass('selected');
                                    $('#inactive').removeClass('selected');
                                    $('#activeList').show();
                                    $('#inactiveList').hide();
                                });
                                $('#inactive').click(function(){
                                    $('#active').removeClass('selected');
                                    $('#inactive').addClass('selected');
                                    $('#activeList').hide();
                                    $('#inactiveList').removeClass('hidden');
                                    $('#inactiveList').show();
                                });
                            });
                            /*]]>*/
        </script>
```

I need to be able to navigate directly to the inactive view upon clicking a link on a separate page. How do I trigger the ('#inactive').click upon accessing the page from a link on a different page? The divs that are to be shown/hidden are not included for the sake of space and simplicity.

Edit: The missing }); unintentionally disappeared with some irrelevant code I removed for clarity's sake.

Comment: Just do `$('#inactive').click()` or `$('#inactive').trigger('click')`

Comment: you appear to be missing a `});`

Comment: Can you provide a little bit more detail about what specifies a "separate page"? Are you just trying to trigger the `('#inactive').click` handler when the page is loaded, or only when the page is loaded as a result of a *specific link* being clicked? In the latter case it might be simple just to pass a url parameter and check for its existence on page load.

Comment: I need to trigger the handler only when the page is loaded as a result of a specific link being clicked.

Comment: You can check the url from the `location` object. `location.href` to be especific.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way, IMO, is to pull the anonymous functions out of the .click() handlers, give them names, then bind the `#inactive` function to run on load as well as on .click(), like so:

```
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        var active = function(){
                            $('#active').addClass('selected');
                            $('#inactive').removeClass('selected');
                            $('#activeList').show();
                            $('#inactiveList').hide();};
                        var inactive = function(){
                            $('#active').removeClass('selected');
                            $('#inactive').addClass('selected');
                            $('#activeList').hide();
                            $('#inactiveList').removeClass('hidden');
                            $('#inactiveList').show();};

                        $('#active').click(active);
                        $('#inactive').click(inactive);
                        inactive();
                    });
```

Comment: Typo at the end of each function, take a look at the closing `)`. And i agree, the cleanest way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Provide a GET value to the page if you click on the link to the page from a specific location.

Let's say the following is your current anchor element from the specific location in question

```
<a href = "mydestinationpage.php">Click me</a>
```

Change it to

```
<a href = "mydestinationpage.php?from=1">Click me</a>
```

On the destination page, grab the GET value

```
$from_value = $_GET["from"];
```

Then look for the value in your JavaScript

```
var from_value = "<?php echo $from_value; ?>";
if(from_value != "" && from_value != null){
    $('#active').removeClass('selected');
           $('#inactive').addClass('selected');
           $('#activeList').hide();
           $('#inactiveList').removeClass('hidden');
           $('#inactiveList').show();
    }
```

If a GET value is provided, the JavaScript code in question is executed.  If there is no GET value, nothing happens

I am assuming you are using PHP with this solution